# Choosing between archetypes and standard class features, can you do that?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, character-levels

When you chose to go into an archetype of a class, do you have to choose the class features of the archetype or can you pick and choose between the alternate class features and the standard ones?

For example, say that someone wanted to play a sandman bard, he feels versatile performance would be more useful then sneak spell, does he have to take sneak spell or can he choose between the 2?

Answer (score 5):

You *must* take all the features of all archetypes you take.  Many of the features are much weaker than the abilities they replace.  Ostensibly, this is to make up for other, more powerful features the archetype possess, but archetypes are not generally balanced with each other and careful consideration should be taken when choosing an archetype to make sure you are actually getting what you think you are getting for your investment.

Answer (score 5):

Only a few archetypes, like the [Qinggong Monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk/), allows you to freely pick between the original abilities and the archetype abilities. Others must follow the [general rules for archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/), which replaces or changes *all* the class abilities listed on the archetype:

> The primary way in which archetypes modify their corresponding base classes is via the use of alternate class features. When a character selects a class, he must normally choose to use the standard class features found in the class’s original source—the exception is if he chooses to adopt an archetype. **Each alternate class feature presented in an archetype replaces a specific class feature from its parent class.** For example, the flowing monk archetype’s redirection class feature replaces the Stunning Fist feature of the standard monk class.
>
> **When an archetype includes multiple alternate class features, a character must take them all—often blocking the character from ever gaining certain standard class features, but replacing them with other options**. All other class features of the base class that aren’t mentioned among the alternate class features remain unchanged and are acquired normally when the character reaches the appropriate level, unless noted otherwise. A character who takes an alternate class feature does not count as having the class feature that was replaced for the purposes of meeting any requirements or prerequisites.
>
> A character can take more than one archetype and garner additional alternate class features, but none of the alternate class features can replace or alter the same class feature.